# List of List<String> to string ordered string array

Tags: java, algorithm, list, csv, opencsv

I am having a `resultList` which is a string list were each element in this list is also a `List<String>`. Now I want to put my data into a csv sheet. For that I am using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

```
    List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for(int m = 0; m < resultList.get(0).size(); m++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {

            data.add(new String[] {resultList.get(i).get(m).toString()});

        }
    }

    writer.writeAll(data);

    //close Writer
    writer.close();
```

My data should look like that:

[image]

However, my implementation gives me that:

[image]

In my implementation I am taking, knowing that every sublist has the same length, from each sublist the first element and add it to the array. Why am I getting this long row?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: @Dukeling Can you recommend any code structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your loop is incorrect. You constructed a new String array in every inner loop, so every array has only on element.
Try the following code:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for(List<String> strlist : resultList) {

    String[] array = new String[strlist.size()];
    int offset = 0;
    for(String s : strlist) {
        array[offset ++] = s;
    }
    data.add(array);
}
```

============== Edited bellow ==================

I've re-ordered the loop to match your output requirement. Also, a sample input is provided to test the algorithm.

```
List<List<String>> resultList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

    List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    resultList.add(innerList);
    for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
        innerList.add(j + "");
    }
}

List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

for(int m = 0; m < resultList.get(0).size(); m++) {

    String[] array = new String[resultList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = resultList.get(i).get(m).toString();
    }
    data.add(array);
}
for(String[] array : data) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Comment: @user2051347: I forgot `data.add(array);`, sorry for that. I've corrected my code.

Comment: Thx for your reply! However what I am currently getting is the resuls column wise and not row by row. Any suggestions how that can be fixed? I really would appreciate your reply!!!

Comment: @user2051347: Please give me a sample input of resultList, and expected output. I'll change the loop order to match your request.

Comment: Thx for your help! Sample input would be to have 3 string lists with the numbers 1 to 9 and then give them out that each row has the numbers 1 to 9(as it can be seen on the first picture). I really appreciate your help!